# PHP Include Navigation Not Appearing in Footer

Tags: php, include, footer

Hi my PHP include is not appearing in my footer and can't figure out why.  When I open the include file it works fine.  Any suggestions? It is the same navigation code I had for other files, but i just moved it to the footer from a navigation bar at the top of the website.  The navigation works in that case.

PHP file:

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div id="navigation">
   <?php require_once ("navigation.inc.php"); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Navigation file:

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <a href="test.php" target="_self">Home</a>
</div>
```

CSS file:

```css
#footer {
 position: absolute;
 clear: left;
 height: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: -5px;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
    background-color: green;

#navigation {
 font-size: 125%;
 padding: 5px;
 bottom: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 border-top: 1px solid black;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 


}

#navigation a {
 color: black;
 padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
 margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}  

#navigation a:hover {
 background-color: #FF8B27;
}
```